# Modifications to the "Walk to infinity on the Gauss primes with steps of bounded length"

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

1.) if this famous unsolved is changed from "Gauss primes" to "square-free Gauss integers", then I think the answer will probably be "Yes" and I hope someone can think of a way to prove it.(Note though the answer is known to be "No" for rational square-free integers.) 2.) If the problem is changed from "Gauss primes" to "Gauss primes and powers of Gauss primes", then the answer might be "No". Perhaps this stronger claim or a related stronger claim could be proven more easily?
I would appreciate kindly comments and information on 1 and 2.